# How to add emoji to a string then add to .ToList

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I'm currently trying to create a Poll command for my Discord BOT. I would like to edit the string `answer` and add an Emoji to the start of that answer based on the number the answer is given.

E.G the user will type ?poll "questionhere" "answer1" "answer2" - i would like to take "answer1" and change to ":one: answer1" and so on but i'm not sure how to go about doing that.

The second thing i would like some advise of if possible is how i am currently managing how many reactions get added to the message, there has got to be a better way of doing what i am doing but i am still fairly new to this and learning so any advise or recommendation on how to better structure the below would be appreciated .

```
//Take the string answer and split into separate strings based on text inside ""
var result = answer.Split('"').Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 1).ToList();

if (result.Count() == 2)
 {

 List<List<string>> listChunks = StaticObjects.SplitIntoChunks<string>(result, 50);

 for (int i = 0; i < listChunks.Count; i++)
  {
    listChunks = listChunks.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
    string description = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, listChunks[i]);

  EmbedBuilder eb = new EmbedBuilder()
  {
    Title = $@":bar_chart:**{question.ToUpper()}**",
    Description = description,
    Color = new Color(0, 0, 127),
  };

var message = await ReplyAsync(embed: eb.Build());
var YourEmoji1 = new Emoji("1\u20e3");
var YourEmoji2 = new Emoji("2\u20e3");
await message.AddReactionAsync(YourEmoji1);
await message.AddReactionAsync(YourEmoji2);
```

currently then continues with `if (result.Count() == 3)`

**Update**
I've found a way to add the Emoji before the string however now i don't know how to pass it back to the original `result`

```
var one = "1\u20e3" + result.ElementAt(0);
```

**Update 2**
I've now managed to get this working :)

added this

```
if (result.Count() == 2)
  {
  var one = "1\u20e3" + " " + "-" + " " + result.ElementAt(0); 
  var two = "2\u20e3" + " " + "-" + " " + result.ElementAt(1);
```

and changed `result` to `one, two`

```
string description = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, one, two);
```

**Update 3**
I've discovered you can change

```
var YourEmoji1 = new Emoji("1\u20e3");
var YourEmoji2 = new Emoji("2\u20e3");
await message.AddReactionAsync(YourEmoji1);
await message.AddReactionAsync(YourEmoji2);
```

to

```
await message.AddReactionAsync(new Emoji("1\u20e3"));
await message.AddReactionAsync(new Emoji("2\u20e3"));
```

I'm now just left with the problem of structuring this in a much more elegant way so the code isn't ridiculously long as i want to allow up to 10 answers

Comment: Additionally, the `AddRectionAsync()` allows you to give it an array. So you could also do `await message.AddRectionAsync(new Emoji[] { new Emoji("1\u20e3"), new Emoji("2\u20e3")});`

Comment: Thanks, ill give this a go, will this still add the emojis in the correct order all the time?

Comment: Apologies for a long response time, i've tried to implement your suggestion however was getting error message "`cannot convert from 'Discord.Emoji[]' to 'Discord.IEmote`'"

Answer (score 1):

Since you've found your solution and now want to just clean up the code, I just have a suggestion for readability:

You don't need to use character codes when you declare your emojis (`new Emoji("1\u20e3")`). Instead, you can use the Discord emoji names, as long as you include the `:`s.
For example: `new Emoji(":one:")`, `new Emoji(":two:")` etc

Similarly, the following can be cleaned up

```cs
  var one = "1\u20e3" + " " + "-" + " " + result.ElementAt(0);
```

To this:

```cs
  var one = ":one: - " + result.ElementAt(0);
```

And so on.

This will not make your code work any better, however it *will* make it more readable.